# FirebaseAuthUI: TermsOfServiceMessage string not displayed

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseAuthUI but at the login-screen the string for `termsOfServiceMessage` is not displayed. Instead the key-value is just shown like you can see here:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix that?

In the `FirebaseAuthUI.strings` from the POD the string is defined like this:

[image]

**Edit**: I have called `setTOSURL()` and `setPrivacyPolicyURL()`

Comment: https://github.com/ramjyroo/firebaseAuthUI-iOS-jyroo/blob/master/FirebaseAuthUI/FUIPrivacyAndTermsOfServiceView.m, Look into this link. It looks like you are missing items.

Comment: @SachinVas What items would I be missing?